# If attribute equals (Kinetic.js)

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, kineticjs

I'm very new to Kinetic.js and I can't find a solution to my problem. I create a new kinetic.line here:

```
var shape = new Kinetic.Line({
color: area.colour
});
```

And I want to use the color attribute in an if loop:

```
stage.on('mouse down', function(evt) {
var shape = evt.targetNode;
if (shape.color == 'red') {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
});
```

This doesn't work, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no color attribute. Use 'fill' instead.
Then use 'mousedown' event instead of 'mouse down'.

```
var shape = new Kinetic.Line({
fill: area.colour
});

stage.on('mousedown', function(evt) {
var shape = evt.targetNode;
    if (shape.getFill() === 'Red') {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
});
```

Take a look at the documentation http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Line.html.